# problema uid diferente android

Tags: android

I am making an application for a library and I need to access a remote database, I'm having problems with this code:

```
llave = accountm.getUserData (mAccounts [i], accountm.KEY_USERDATA);
```

I have this line in a loop incrementing the variable i, when my program reaches this line there is an error and my application quits unexpectedly. In the logcat of eclipse I have the uid is different.

Here is the code of the entire function:

```
public ArrayList<Grabar> getItems(Context ctx, URL url)throws IOException {

        try {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            xr.setContentHandler(this);

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputSource is;


        // Build the baseURL in-case we're given relative links in our RSS feed
        baseURL = url.getProtocol() + "://" + url.getHost();
        if ( url.getPort() > 0 )
            baseURL += ":" + url.getPort();         
            AccountManager accountm = AccountManager.get(ctx);
            //Account[] mAccounts = accountm.getAccountsByType("nz.net.catalyst.KiritakiKoha.account");
            Account[] mAccounts = accountm.getAccounts();
            String llave;
            for (int i=0; i < mAccounts.length; i++) {

                    llave=accountm.getUserData(mAccounts[i], accountm.KEY_USERDATA);

                    System.out.println(mAccounts[i]);

                    if ( llave.length() > 0 ) {
                        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", llave);
                        break;
                    }
            }

            is = new InputSource(conn.getInputStream());
            xr.parse(is);
            return Grabars;

    } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getItems: IOException: " + e.toString());
            throw new IOException("Connection failed.");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getItems: SAXException: " + e.toString());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getItems: ParserConfigurationException: " + e.toString());
    }

    return Grabars;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al Stack Overflow! Por favor haga preguntas aquí en Inglés. *Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ask questions here in English.*

Comment: what?! maybe use google translate?